# PHP session cookie not saved on android

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I wrote a php web application that uses php sessions. When I tried it on an Android phone, it turned out, that the browser is not keeping the session cookie.
I boiled it down to this super short test script:

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_COOKIE);
?>
```

The expected behaviour as I can see it in another browser is:
On the first call we see :

```
array(0) { }
```

On the second and subsequent calls we see something like:

```
array(1) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(32) "8f08c514a5c15c36309e9a435ebcc8ec" }
```

On the Android phone, the `$_COOKIE` array however stays empty and I get the first response (`array(0) { }`) all the time.

I checked the settings and cookies were enabled. Also other websites (not written by me) that require logins did work fine.
I also tried to clear all cookies and the cache just in case, but it did not change anything.

**edit:** To clarify, session_start() is supposed to set the sesssion cookie and it actually works using Firefox on a desktop pc. I also had a look into the http headers and found

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=a270cbe1b57ba089c1eedacd8344e871; path=/
```

So the cookie definitely gets set. Unless, of course, PHP does something different when serving an Android browser.

Is this a known problem or am I missing something obvious? And is there a workaround?

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the cookie with your test script? You don't appear to be setting anything in that short script you posted.

Comment: You must add data to cookie first and then try the var_dump

Comment: session_start() is supposed to set the session cookie automatically. This is observed using a firefox browser.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question, but I just came across the same issue and couldn't find an answer anywhere on StackOverflow or Google, so I thought I would share my solution.

Some browsers (mostly mobile) will insert "www" if you are not using a subdomain.  For example if your site is example.com, the browser will change it to www.example.com.

If your session was set on example.com, that is what the session cookie is set to as well, and it will not be recognized on www.example.com.
The easiest way I know of to fix this is to add the following lines to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s/%1 ^(on(s)|offs)/(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%3%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Hopefully this will help someone out with the same problem :-)